# Class not found exception in Spring boot application deployment to external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat8

I have recently upgraded spring boot application from 1.3.1 to 1.5.10 version and Gradle from 2.7 to 3.5. I have fixed all the errors regarding upgrade and is working fine with IDE (STS). But when I am trying to deploy the war to external tomcat getting **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestRule**.

The application was working fine with old configuration only updated spring boot and Gradle version.

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestRule
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2270)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.rules.TestRule
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
22-Jan-2020 12:35:33.963 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.projectx.SpringIntegrationApplication
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestRule
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2270)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.rules.TestRule
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 42 more

22-Jan-2020 12:35:33.965 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/ROOT.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
     //   springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
     springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
     googleAPIClientVersion='1.2.3-alpha'
     googleAPIClientJacksonVersion='1.23.0'     
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath ('org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.2')
        //classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' 
//apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert'


war {
    baseName = 'ROOT'

}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-twitter:4.0.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.RELEASE')        
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3')
    compile('javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:1.2')
    compile('com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.5')
    compile('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.4.5')
    compile('com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.6')

    //excel sheet
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6')
    compile ('org.dstadler:commons-dost:1.0.0.23')
    compile ('com.google.guava:guava:21.0')
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5')
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.17'

    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:1.1.0")           
   // testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
//    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+")     
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")  
    compile("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:1.1.1.RELEASE")
    //compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.75')

    //Deploy on same tomcat with diffrent domain dependancy
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-jmx', version: '4.3.0.RELEASE' 

    //JJWT
    compile ('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'

    //AWS S3 SDK
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.86'
    //AWS SES SDK
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-ses', version: '1.11.86'    
    //AWS SSM SDK
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-ssm', version: '1.11.665'
    //AWS EC2
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-ec2', version: '1.11.665'

    //SafetyNet
    //compile group: 'com.google.api.client', name: 'google-api-client-json', version: googleAPIClientVersion
    compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-jackson2', version: googleAPIClientJacksonVersion

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot-starter
    compile group: 'com.github.ulisesbocchio', name: 'jasypt-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.9'

    //Firebase    
    compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '5.2.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator 
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    compile('com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.1')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-ip
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-ip', version: '4.3.0.RELEASE'

    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core') 

    //mysql connection pooling
    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.4.6'
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.5'
}

ext {
    snippetsDir = file('build/generated-snippets')
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

asciidoctor {
    attributes 'snippets': snippetsDir
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}
```

Guide me to diagnose this issue. Also want to know why tomcat loading junit class at run time.

Your suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding compile time dependency for junit. I am unclrear why spring boot 1.5 need Junit dependency at runtime, If any know please explain it.